# How To Mount USD External Storage Drive on to ESXi 5.5 Host for VM backup

Tags: usb, storage, vmware, esxi

How To Mount USD External Storage Drive on to ESXi 5.5 Host for VM backup

After USB Drive plugin, "esxcli storage core device list" shows there is a usb drive attached. But unable to access it.

"esxcli storage core device list "

mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0
   Display Name: Local USB Direct-Access (mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0)
   Has Settable Display Name: false
   Size: 1907729
   Device Type: Direct-Access 
   Multipath Plugin: NMP
   Devfs Path: /vmfs/devices/disks/mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0
   Vendor: Seagate 
   Model: BUP Slim BL
   Revision: 0108
   SCSI Level: 2
   Is Pseudo: false
   Status: on
   Is RDM Capable: false
   Is Local: true
   Is Removable: true
   Is SSD: false
   Is Offline: false
   Is Perennially Reserved: false
   Queue Full Sample Size: 0
   Queue Full Threshold: 0
   Thin Provisioning Status: unknown
   Attached Filters: 
   VAAI Status: unsupported
   Other UIDs: vml.0000000000766d68626133383a303a30
   Is Local SAS Device: false
   Is USB: true
   Is Boot USB Device: false
   No of outstanding IOs with competing worlds: 32

"esxcli storage core path list -d mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0"

usb.vmhba38-usb.0:0-mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0
   UID: usb.vmhba38-usb.0:0-mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0
   Runtime Name: vmhba38:C0:T0:L0
   Device: mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0
   Device Display Name: Local USB Direct-Access (mpx.vmhba38:C0:T0:L0)
   Adapter: vmhba38
   Channel: 0
   Target: 0
   LUN: 0
   Plugin: NMP
   State: active
   Transport: usb
   Adapter Identifier: usb.vmhba38
   Target Identifier: usb.0:0
   Adapter Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed
   Target Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed
   Maximum IO Size: 122880

Note: I stopped usbarbitrator.

/etc/init.d/usbarbitrator status

usbarbitrator is not running

Please advice.

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) (Please check the spelling (title, too): is USD related to $US? To make machine output/messages stand out, try *block quotes*: put `> ` before each line, or mark and use "the `“”`/*block quote* button (or its keyboard short-cut) in the post editor.)

Answer (score 0):

There are very few USB drives that work directly against an ESXi host, and versions prior to 6.0 had a very strict ruleset against mounting unsupported devices.

I'm assuming you're attempting to mount the USB drive as a VMFS volume, which is unsupported regardless of what version, however there is a list of supported devices that work for passthrough activities. I would assume these could be used as VMFS mounts as well: https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1021345

While it looks like you're following the proper steps, here's a detailed list that may help: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2065934

Alternatively, since USB performance is generally pretty slow on ESXi hosts, you could also perform your backup activities on the VM and then SCP the files off the ESXi host to the USB drive.